# Eclipse Java. Struggling, prompting the user to enter a file location and adding a stopwords.txt file

Tags: java, eclipse

just struggling to understand this code I have got. im not sure where to go about adding a prompt for the user. right now my code is automatically accepting input from my java script and its pre-defined location. But I need help making it so when I give it to a user' they define the .txt files location instead of me.  I then want this .txt file to be scanned through another .txt file that contains stop words to remove unnecessary words and only display the main words I have selected.

TLDR: Struggling making my code a user prompt asking for file location of a .txt
I then want this .txt file to go through a array list of stop words which is defined on another .txt file in the same directory. Ive been pulling my hair out for hours. help would be appreciated.

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;


 public class DocumentReader {

// List of stopwrods to remove.
String[] stopwords = {"a","the", "an", "is", "and", "of", "in", "at", "for", "with", "as", "it", "its", "to", "like", "have", "has", "had", "such", "many", "on", "this"};
// List of punctuation marks to remove.
String[] punctuation = {"'s", "'", ".", "!", "?", ",", ";", ":"};


public ArrayList<String> readDocument(String location) {
    String document = "";

    try {
        Scanner docInput = new Scanner(new File(location));

        while(docInput.hasNext()) document = document.concat(docInput.nextLine());
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println();
    }

    return tokeniseDocument(document);
}

/*
 * Removes any basic punctuation and returns unpunctuated String.
 */
public String removePunctuation(String document) {
    for(String punct : punctuation) { // Loop through all of the elements of basic punctuation.
        document = document.replace(punct, ""); // Remove any punctuation found.
    }

    return document.toLowerCase(); // Lowercase the document and return it.
}

/*
 * Returns true if the term is contained in the stopword list.
 */
public boolean isStopword(String term) {
    boolean found = false; // Have we found this term in the list of stopwords yet?

    for(String stopword : stopwords) { // Loop through all of the terms in the stopword list.
        if(term.equals(stopword)) {
            found = true; // If list contains term then set found variable to true.
        }
    }

    return found;
}

/*
 * Tokenises the document and returns an ArrayList of constituent terms.
 */
public ArrayList<String> tokeniseDocument(String document) {
    ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>(); // ArrayList to store the final list of tokens (seperated terms)

    for(String token : removePunctuation(document).split(" ")) { // Remove any punctuation and tokenise the document by spaces.
        if(!isStopword(token)) { 
         tokens.add(token); // If the current token is not a stopword then add it to the ArrayList.
        }
    }

    return tokens;  // Return the final list of tokens.
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DocumentReader reader = new DocumentReader();

    // Read in one of the documents and print out all of its constituent tokens.

    for(String token : reader.readDocument("g:\\portugal.txt"))
        System.out.println(token);
}
```

}

Comment: If you don't understand the code you've been given, how are you going to understand any code that anyone on Stack Overflow might give you?  You should hire a tutor to help you understand basic Java.

Comment: how about some productive help?

Comment: Ok.  Spend a few months going through the [Oracle Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).  You said you're struggling to understand the code you've been given.  I hope thatr you can understand the tutorials.

Comment: I don't have months, I need help for an assignment, if your not offering productive help. go away quite frankly. Im 20 years old trying to understand java and get to grips with it. Simply telling me to view tutorials which I have done for the past 9 months. Is not a good enough answer. Thanks.